# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. XAMPP local conf running WordPress

Tags: mysql, errors, xampp

I have a xampp configurated locally to run wordpress. I must have done something wrong when fixing some issues 'cuz at the end, I got stuck with the following log from mysql database.

```
2015-11-10 15:26:56 10fc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1835027
2015-11-10 15:26:57 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown
--------

2018-07-19 21:28:34 568 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2018-07-19 21:28:34 1384 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-07-19 21:28:34 1384 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-07-19 21:28:34 1384 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2018-07-19 21:28:34 1384 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2018-07-19 21:28:34 1384 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-07-19 21:28:34 1384 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2018-07-19 21:28:34 1384 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.0G
2018-07-19 21:28:34 1384 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-07-19 21:28:34 1384 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-07-19 21:28:34 1384 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 0 in ibdata file do not match the log sequence number 49463 in the ib_logfiles!
2018-07-19 21:28:34 1384 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
2018-07-19 21:28:34 1384 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2018-07-19 21:28:35 1384 [Note] InnoDB: Tablespace and datafile system tables created.
2018-07-19 21:28:35 1384 [Warning] InnoDB: Resizing redo log from 2*320 to 2*16384 pages, LSN=53524
2018-07-19 21:28:35 1384 [Warning] InnoDB: Starting to delete and rewrite log files.
2018-07-19 21:28:35 1384 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 256 MB
2018-07-19 21:28:35 1384 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 256 MB
2018-07-19 21:28:35 1384 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2018-07-19 21:28:35 1384 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=53772
2018-07-19 21:28:35 1384 [Note] InnoDB: 1 rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-07-19 21:28:35 1384 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted at D:\win32-packages\build\src\storage\xtradb\srv\srv0start.cc [2969] with error Generic error.
2018-07-19 21:28:35 1384 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-07-19 21:28:35 1384 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-07-19 21:28:35 1384 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2018-07-19 21:28:35 1384 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2018-07-19 21:28:35 1384 [ERROR] Aborting
```

this guy here seems to repeat itself a number of times - I know, It is specific. I know, I almost know it like poetry but still, I can not find the solution. I have tried several methods found all over the internet, some of them be

*deleting ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1
*increasing InnoDB buffer pool size
*removing the 'sys_malloc' from db configuration

Bellow I'll paste the my.ini file of my sql server

```
    # Example MySQL config file for small systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
# doesn't use much resources.
#
# You can copy this file to
# D:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is D:/xampp/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client] 
# password       = your_password 
port            = 3306 
socket          = "D:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 4
port= 3306
socket = "D:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "D:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "D:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "D:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 20M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 20M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"
innodb_use_sys_malloc = 1


# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir = "D:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/" 

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
#skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "D:/xampp/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = "D:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "D:/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "D:/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 200M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 200M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 200M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="D:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 20M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

I'm quite newbie to mysql, and trying all those stuffs without even changing the error... sucks. And I'll probably suck more untill I rock (ya, I just did that one for not letting you guys take advantage). Cheers!

Comment: innodb_log_file_size should NEVER be smaller than innodb_log_buffer_size.  You appear to have them reversed for the sizes to make sense. 
REMOVE innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 200M from your my.cnf it is DEPRECATED.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I approached to solve the problem.

I have fixed the issue. From xampp/mysql/backup/ folder i copied all files in to xampp/mysql/data/ That solved the issue.

Comment: copying all files from xampp/mysql/backup/ folder in to xampp/mysql/data/ solved the issue.

Comment: @SeySey please mark my comment as an answer. Thanks